# MPI_Recv overwrites parts of memory it should not access

Tags: fortran, mpi

In the following code the value of `xysize` gets changed, if I do not declare it as a parameter (which I generally cannot do). It happens only with optimizations -O2 and more in gfortran 4.7.2 and OpenMPI 1.6. How is it possible? I cannot find the exact interface, that I import from `mpi.mod`, but the C prototype clearly states that `count` is passed by value, hence it cannot change.

```
     write(*,*) im,"receiving from",image_index([iim,jim,kim+1]),"size",&
      size(D%A(D%starti:D%endi,D%startj:D%endj,D%endk)),xysize

    call MPI_RECV(D%A(D%starti:D%endi,D%startj:D%endj,D%endk+1),xysize , MPI_REAL, image_index([iim,jim,kim+1])-1,&
           5000, comm, status, ierr)

    write(*,*) im,"received size",&
      size(D%A(D%starti:D%endi,D%startj:D%endj,D%endk)),xysize
```

output:

```
1 receiving from           2 size        4096        4096
1 received size        4096        5000
```

Comment: Our of curiosity, what do you get from `mpi_get_count(status,MPI_REAL,n,ierr); print*, n` -- I'm really wondering if you're getting a buffer overflow which is causing funny behavior...

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! The problem was apparently in the declaration in status, which was a normal scalar integer. I don't know why it compiled in `MPI_Recv`, because the interface check for `MPI_Get_count` caught this.

Comment: Weird.  I'm glad that it caught it though.  `MPI_Recv` might have an interface declared as `integer status(*)` so that it can accept a scalar or an array.  That way, `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` could be a scalar ... Seems like `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` would be small enough that it wouldn't matter, but, I suppose the library is trying to be memory efficient or something ... `MPI_Get_count` on the other hand can't accept `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` ...

Comment: @mgilson, `MPI_RECV` (as well as any other routine that takes user data buffers as arguments) can take zillions of different data types as its first argument and for that reason is almost never present in the module interface. One has to compile Open MPI with special flags in order to enable interfaces of such routines to be generated. Then it takes REALLLLLLY LOOOOONG time to compile and only covers a relatevly small subset of the types possible. An interim solution is comming in MPI 3.0 - there are new F2008 bindings defined that use the `TYPE(*), DIMENSION(..)` feature of F2008.

Comment: Also another feature of F2008, `ASYNCHRONOUS` is used in the new MPI 3.0 interfaces of the non-blocking calls like `MPI_Isend`. This means that with a fully F2008 compliant compiler in palce, one would be able to safely pass array subsections to non-blocking calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of future visitors, I suppose I'll answer this even though it's all answered in the comments above.

As far as I'm aware, if your program is behaving properly, you cannot change the value of that parameter ("count") in a call to `MPI_Recv`.

Your argument `status` is too small, it should be an array `status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)`, and you're getting a buffer overflow -- This often results in a segmentation fault, but at times (depending on how the compiler packed the variables in memory), it can result in funny behavior like this.

Comment: This mostly happens when stack variables are used as call parameters and no pointer in use gets overwritten/corrupted (with the return address in the stack frame of the calling function being such a pointer).

Comment: @HristoIliev -- Clearly you haven't worked with some of the codes that I have ;-).  Old f77 style memory management where everything is `equivalence`d in 1 big array that gets partitioned when passed to subroutines ... :)

Comment: Hey, it's 2012, we have like GCC... and cookies :)