# MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED: memory limited?

Tags: fortran, mpi, shared-memory

It seems like whenever I am trying to allocate a window around 30-32 Mb I get a segmentation fault?

I am using following routine `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED`

Does anybody know if there is a limit to how big my window can be? If so, is there a way to compile my code relaxing that limit?

I am using INTEL MPI 19.0.3 and ifort 19.0.3 -

Example written in Fortran. By varying the integer `size_` you can see when the segmentation fault occurs. I tested it with `size_=10e3` and `size_=10e4` the latter caused a segmentation fault

```
C------
      program TEST_STACK
      use, INTRINSIC ::ISO_C_BINDING

      implicit none
      include 'mpif.h'

      !---  Parameters (They should not be changed ! )
      integer, parameter   :: whoisroot   = 0  ! - Root always 0 here
      !---  General parallel
      integer              :: whoami                 ! - My rank
      integer              :: mpi_nproc              ! - no. of procs
      integer              :: mpierr                 ! - Error status
      integer              :: status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)! - For MPI_RECV
      !---  Shared memory stuff
      integer              :: whoami_shm             ! - Local rank in shared memory group
      integer              :: mpi_shm_nproc          ! - No. of procs in Shared memory group
      integer              :: no_partners            ! - No. of partners for share memory
      integer              :: info_alloc
      !---  MPI groups
      integer              :: world_group            ! - All procs across all nodes
      integer              :: shared_group           ! - Only procs that share memory
      integer              :: MPI_COMM_SHM           ! - Shared memory communicators (for those in shared_group)

      type(C_PTR)                         :: ptr_buf
      integer(kind = MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)    :: size_bytes, lb
      integer                             :: win, size_, disp_unit

      call MPI_INIT        ( mpierr )
      call MPI_COMM_RANK   ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, whoami, mpierr )

      call MPI_COMM_RANK   ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, whoami, mpierr )
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE   ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_nproc, mpierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE( MPI_COMM_WORLD
     &                        , MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED
     &                        , 0
     &                        , MPI_INFO_NULL
     &                        , MPI_COMM_SHM
     &                        , mpierr )

      call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_SHM, whoami_shm, mpierr )
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_SHM, mpi_shm_nproc, mpierr )
      size_ = 10e4! - seg fault 
      size_bytes = size_ * MPI_REAL
      disp_unit  = MPI_REAL
      size_bytes = size_*disp_unit
      call MPI_INFO_CREATE( info_alloc, mpierr )
      call MPI_INFO_SET( info_alloc
     &                    , "alloc_shared_noncontig"
     &                    , "true"
     &                    , mpierr )
      !


      call MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED( size_bytes
     &                            , disp_unit
     &                            , info_alloc
     &                            , MPI_COMM_SHM
     &                            , ptr_buf
     &                            , win
     &                            , mpierr )

      call MPI_WIN_FREE(win, mpierr)


      end program TEST_STACK
```

I run my code using following command

`mpif90 test_stack.f90;  mpirun -np 2 ./a.out`

This wrapper is linked to my ifort 19.0.3 and Intel MPI library. This has been verified by running
`mpif90 -v`

and to be very **precise** my `mpif90` is a symbolic link to my `mpiifort` wrapper. This is made for personal convenience but shouldn't be causing problems I guess?

Comment: Also include your MPI library vendor and version, the limit, if any, could be implementation dependent.

Comment: In fact in this case you should use mpi_f08 - you shouldn't use Type( c_ptr ) with the older forms (and you should never use the include file nowadays, the module should be used )

Comment: D'oh, of course if you use mpi_f08 you should be using the appropriate MPI derived types as well

Comment: @IanBush, using `use mpi` should be perfectly valid for this?

Comment: @A2LBK No, you can never say that `use mpi` will catch your error, that is simply not true. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049648/mpi-recv-overwrites-parts-of-memory-it-should-not-access#comment17745759_13049648 You must check the correctness of the call carefully. Each argument one by one.

Comment: I am not saying it will catch my error!. What I am saying is that `use mpi` should contain the features I am using, hence perfectly valid - I don't know whether use mpi would be worse for debugging  or not. I am happy to share the OpenMPI manual version 3.1 with you

Comment: OK, I don't really care what the OpenMPI manual says, but according to the MPI standard document I am wrong, though I'm a bit surprised as it allows such a horrible mix of styles. Anyway see https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node263.htm#Node263 for what the 3.1 standard says. But @VladimirF is right, you have the wrong kind for the disp_unit argument if you want to do it this way.

Comment: @IanBush; the `disp_unit` was actually a typo. I will change this in the code, as I did not meant that to be the case

Comment: The program deos not crash for me. You will also have to tell us how exactly you are compiling it and running it.

Comment: I am compiling using Ifort 19.0.3 and running with mpirun -np 2

Comment: I do see that it runs when doing `mpirun -np 1` but that is not really helpful when increasing no. of cores beyond 1

Comment: And as for @IanBush comment, the link shows that you can use `type(c_ptr)` in `use mpi`. The issue I got was my `disp_unit`. However, this does not solve the problem, as my realistic case did not have that typo with regards to the declaration of `disp_unit`

Comment: What does it mean "compiling using Ifort 19.0.3"? Which commands do you use? Is `mpirun -np 2` really the complete command? Edit your question with the details.

Comment: Not the comment, edit your question. Do not use comments for important information. Put there the **exact** commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual says that the call to `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED` looks like this

```
USE MPI

MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(SIZE, DISP_UNIT, INFO, COMM, BASEPTR, WIN, IERROR)
    INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) SIZE, BASEPTR
    INTEGER DISP_UNIT, INFO, COMM, WIN, IERROR
```

At least the types of `disp_unit` and `baseptr` do not match in your program.

Comment: That does not solve the problem? As a side note: I have seen some course materials who does use `type(c_ptr)` in combination with `use mpi`. Although, probably better to stick to the manuals exactly

Comment: Sorry about the `disp_unit`, I was meant to declare this as an integer without the kind thing. But even when declaring the `baseptr` as an integer the error persists.

Comment: @A2LBK The problem is likely in `disp_unit`, `INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)` is normally binary compatible with `type(c_ptr)`.

Comment: @A2LBK It does not crash for me.

Comment: @A2LBK Neither for me on 1, 2 or 8 procs after I add a mpi_finalise to the program (the crash without it wasn't a segv). Using gfortran 8.2.0 with openmpi 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to diagnose where the error stems from.

In the code I have

```
  disp_unit  = MPI_REAL
  size_bytes = size_*disp_unit
```

`MPI_REAL` is a constant/parameter defined by MPI and **is not** equal to 4 as I very wrongly expected (4 for 4 bytes for single precision)!. In my version it is set to `1275069468` which most likely refers to an id rather than any sensible number.
Hence, multiplying this number with the size of my array can very quickly exceeds the available memory, but and also the number of digits that can be represented by a byte integer

Comment: The MPI datatype variables and constants are *handles*. Some of them are predefined but generally they can be created, commited and freed again. The number is just a handle of such a type which can be a complicated structure for vectors, subarrays and so on... It is a whole large topic http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-data.html